# Accessing App Arguments from Detox in React Native

Tags: react-native, testing, detox

I'm trying to figure out how to access launch args in Detox from React Native. [The official docs](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/launch-args#in-app-arguments-access) only provide the following information:

> ### In-App Arguments Access​
>
> On iOS, the specified launch arguments are passed as the process launch arguments and available through normal means.
>
> On Android, the launch arguments are set as bundle-extra’s into the activity’s intent. It will therefore be accessible on the native side via the current activity as: currentActivity.getIntent().getBundleExtra("launchArgs").
>
> Further, handling of these launch arguments is up to the user’s responsibility and is out of scope for Detox.

So how can this be done from React Native? The docs only explain native ways (swift or android).

Ideally, if there is a way to do this, then for each test I can set the `launchargs` I need:

```
await device.launchApp({
    launchArgs: {
        MOCK_SOMETHING_IN_THE_APP_FLAG: true,
    },
});
```

My current 'solution' is derived somewhat [from this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223923/react-native-detox-mocking-files), where I run the metro bundler in multiple separate instances, each with a different env depending on which test I am running, which feels way too complicated for something (I think) should be simple.

Ideally, I want to call detox once and more or less 'inject' a sort of environment variable per test. Maybe due to react native's tooling this just isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Detox responsability ends when making sure specified launch arguments (`launchArguments`) reach the native "side" of your app. It's your responsibility to figure out how to read those launch values and get them to your js code. There are some native libraries that might help you:

- [react-native-launch-arguments](https://github.com/iamolegga/react-native-launch-arguments)

Installing this library allows you to read launch arguments like:

```js
import { LaunchArguments } from "react-native-launch-arguments";
LaunchArguments.value();
```

I had some issues with it, so it might only work with newer react native versions.

- [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

I use this library to have different env variables depending on the build type (dev, staging, prod) but it can also be used for a `test` build (the one Detox will use).

One drawback is that you don't want to do a new build for each of your tests, so this might only work for values that don't change between tests, like a mock server, or some generic boolean like `isDetoxTest` or something like that.